# I have three pushbuttons where only one can be pushed at a time and want to set a variable for this. How?

Tags: loop

Basically I have three push buttons that correspond to pins 1 to 3 and want to set an efficient code that sets a certain variable into the index whose digitalRead is equal to one. Let us assume that only one button can be pressed at a time.

```
void loop()
    {
    if(digitalRead(1) == 1)                       
        {
        Variable = 1;            
        }
    if(digitalRead(2) == 1)                       
        {
        Variable = 2;              
        }
    if(digitalRead(3) == 1)                       
        {
        Variable = 3;  
        }
    }
```

Is there are more efficient way to do this, like for example using other loops?

I can't wrap around my head with doing this concept using the other loops such as for, do while, while and switch because the nature of the idea feels so unconventional for their uses.

Comment: "Efficient" is very subjective. Using a for loop will decrease code size, but increase execution time. Using discrete ifs like that will increase code size but decrease execution time.

Comment: What exactly is the role of the `Variable` in your code? Can the values be arbitrary, or are they pin numbers, or are they indices of the pressed buttons? You could use a for loop to go other an array of pins and assign the variable with the element of a second array. I'm not sure, what the actual goal is here, so it is difficult to suggest a good way.

Comment: And how is this question different from your previous one?

Comment: Okay it was pretty much the same, this one can be closed since you gave a good answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If you can only have one button pushed at a time, you can only end up with at most one of the if statements evaluate to true. In your code, you check button 2 and 3, even if button 1 is pressed. Your code can be a bit faster if you do this:

```
if(digitalRead(1) == 1)                       
{
  Variable = 1;            
}
else if(digitalRead(2) == 1)                       
{
  Variable = 2;              
}
else if(digitalRead(3) == 1)                       
{
  Variable = 3;  
}
```